# req.body() is getting empty while inserting data in MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have MERN project where i have to simply put my form data in my database. All looking good but data is not inserting. while there is no error also.

I have done `console.log(req.body)`. after i getting empty `{}`.

*As i have tried so many previous question in stackoverflow but noe of them helps me*

*this is my screenshot of console of my browser*

[image: browser screenshot]

*Showing staus 201 but data is not going in my database*

**How to debug this error. I have tried all solution. Atleast tell me the possible reasons of this error. it will help me a lot. i am trying from full 1 day**

**userSchema**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    identity: {
            type: String,  
    },
    names: {
            type: String,
    },
   
    phone: { 
            type: String,  
    },
    email: {
            type: String,
    },
    city: {
            type: String,
    },
    address: {
            type: String,
    },
    subject: {
            type: String,    
    },
    classes: {
            type: String, 
    },
    message: {
            type: String,
    },
})

const USER = mongoose.model("USER", userSchema)

module.exports = USER
```

**register.js(frontend)**

```
const Register = () => {
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({
    identity: "",
    names: "",
    phone: "",
    email: "",
    city: "",
    address: "",
    subject: "",
    classes: "",
    message: "",
  });



  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("identity", newUser.identity);
    formData.append("names", newUser.names);
    formData.append("phone", newUser.phone);
    formData.append("email", newUser.email);
    formData.append("city", newUser.city);
    formData.append("address", newUser.address);
    formData.append("subject", newUser.subject);
    formData.append("classes", newUser.classes);
    formData.append("message", newUser.message);

    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/register",
      data: formData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
        }
      });
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setNewUser({ ...newUser, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  

  return (
    <>
      <div class="container register mt-5">
        <h1 class="well text-register shadow p-4 rounded-3">
          Join as{" "}
          <label class="student">
            [{" "}
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-vitaliy-gorbachev-lineal-color-vitaly-gorbachev/60/000000/external-man-avatars-vitaliy-gorbachev-lineal-color-vitaly-gorbachev-12.png" />{" "}
            Parent/Student{" "}
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-justicon-lineal-color-justicon/64/000000/external-student-back-to-school-justicon-lineal-color-justicon.png" />{" "}
            ]
          </label>
          <h1 class="well text-register down">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> Hey! If you are looking for right
            tutor near by your location. Don't worry you are at right place.{" "}
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
          </h1>
        </h1>

        <div class="col-lg-12 well rounded-3">
          <div class="row mt-5 ">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}  method = "post" class="shadow p-5">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <label>
                      {" "}
                      <i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i> Your Identity
                    </label>
                    <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Write Student or Parent"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="identity"
                    id="identity"
                    value={newUser.identity}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>
                    {" "}
                    <i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i> Name
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter Your Full Name Here.."
                    class="form-control"
                    name="names"
                    id="names"
                    value={newUser.names}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>
                    {" "}
                    <i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i> Phone Number
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter Phone Number Here.."
                    class="form-control"
                    name="phone"
                    id="phone"
                    value={newUser.phone}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>
                    {" "}
                    <i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i> Email Address
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter Email Address Here.."
                    class="form-control"
                    name="email"
                    id="email"
                    value={newUser.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>
                      {" "}
                      <i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i> City
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter City Name Here.."
                      class="form-control"
                      name="city"
                      id="city"
                      value={newUser.city}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>
                      {" "}
                      <i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i> Address
                    </label>
                    <textarea
                      placeholder="Enter Address Here.."
                      rows="3"
                      class="form-control"
                      name="address"
                      id="address"
                      value={newUser.address}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    ></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>
                      {" "}
                      <i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i> Subject
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter Subject Here.."
                      class="form-control"
                      name="subject"
                      id="subject"
                      value={newUser.subject}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>
                      {" "}
                      <i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i>Student Class
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter Student Class"
                      class="form-control"
                      name="classes"
                      id="classes"
                      value={newUser.classes}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>
                    {" "}
                    <i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i> Message
                  </label>
                  <textarea
                    placeholder="Enter Any message you have for us..."
                    rows="3"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="message"
                    id="message"
                    value={newUser.message}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  ></textarea>
                </div>
                <button value="register" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">
                  Submit
                </button>

              </div>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

**auth.js**

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello, i am communicating with router");
})


router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const { identity, names, phone, email, city, address, subject, classes, message } = req.body
    console.log(req.body)

    try {
    
            const user = new User({identity ,names,  phone,email,city,address, subject, classes, message })
            await user.save()
            res.status(201).json({ message: "user registered successfulluy" })
        
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

})


module.exports = router
```

**app.js**

```
const port = 5000
env.config({path: "../server/config.env"})
require("../server/db/conn")
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(require("../server/router/Auth"))


app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Please help. i have tried so many times!!

Thankyou!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify Your HandleSubmit function, do not use formData to submit your data as application/json

Instead, just use your current React State

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/register",
      data: JSON.stringify(newUser),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
        }
      });
  };
```